# Restricting publishing for specified publication while publishing from parent publication | Custom Resolver

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing, resolving

Is there any way to restrict  publishing to specified child publication while publishing from parent publication.

We have a requirement where we don't want to publish content for few publication if published from master/parent publication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top of my head, one way to achieve this is to:

1. Implement a [custom resolver](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/a-custom-resolver-in-practice)
2. Implement logic in it checking if this is a "publish from parent" instruction
3. Check if you're currently resolving for one of these publications you don't want to publish
4. Override the resolvedItems collection to contain 0 items.

I'm sure there's many more ways to do it, but this would likely work. Do remember that when publishing Tridion creates one transaction per publication, so I don't think you could just exclude a specific publication from the transaction itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an option. You can always remove some publications from publication target. If you do this, it will mean that publishing (or unpublishing) from that publication will no longer be possible.

This option is if you don't want publishing from these publications at all.

If indeed you need just publishing from publication enabled, but without anything published, you can implement custom resolver as @Nuno mentioned. This solution will enable publishing, but will remove all items at resolve time, which will result in empty transactions.

Can you please update your question so that its understood what is the exact requirement and what you want to achieve?